# Two AND/OR in one bash if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a special condition to test in a bash script.
I thought about something like:

```
if [[ $categorie = "DG" || $categorie = "DI" ]] && [[ $client != "host1" || $client != "host2" ]]; then
    echo "requirements are met"
else
    echo "requirements not met"
fi
```

In words: If `categorie` is `DG` OR `DI` AND `client` is NOT `host1` OR `host2` then do stuff.

Is this correct?
For me it looks like it just cares about the `categorie` and if the `categorie` condition is met it's ok and prints "requirements are met" and doesn't care about the condition for the client at all.

Comment: You are quoting the wrong things. All variables should be quoted to avoid surprises with word-splitting and glob expansion, for all literals it's redundant.

Comment: @Jens i thought the double-brackets will prevent this?

Comment: Maybe, they are non-standard (in bash they do, you are right). The (POSIX Standard) single brackets would not prevent this.

Comment: In `[[ ]]`, quotes only make a difference on the right side of `=`/`==`/`!=` (quoted: treated as string, unquoted: treated as glob pattern) and on the right side of `=~` (quoted: treated as string since Bash 3.2, unquoted: treated as regular expression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English and logic ascribe different meanings to negated OR — it is very easy to get confused.

Think about possible values for `$client`; they are 'host1', 'host2', and 'other'.  If the value is 'host1' the second term in the `||` is true; if it is 'host2', the first term in the `||` is true; if it is 'other' both terms in the `||` are true; which means the condition is always true.

Replace that `||` with `&&` — if the client is not equal to host1 and is not equal to host2.

```
if [[ "$categorie" = "DG" || "$categorie" = "DI" ]] &&
   [[ "$client" != "host1" && "$client" != "host2" ]]; then
    echo "requirements are met"
else
    echo "requirements not met"
fi
```

Or use `!(client == host1 || client == host2)` which can be translated to:

```
if [[ "$categorie" = "DG" || "$categorie" = "DI" ]] &&
   [[ ! ( "$client" = "host1" || "$client" = "host2" ) ]]; then
    echo "requirements are met"
else
    echo "requirements not met"
fi
```

Putting it into a test script:

```
for categorie in DG DI XX
do
    for client in host1 host2 other
    do
        if [[ "$categorie" = "DG" || "$categorie" = "DI" ]] &&
           [[ "$client" != "host1" && "$client" != "host2" ]]; then
            echo "(categorie $categorie; client $client): requirements are met"
        else
            echo "(categorie $categorie; client $client): requirements not met"
        fi
        if [[ "$categorie" = "DG" || "$categorie" = "DI" ]] &&
           [[ ! ( "$client" = "host1" || "$client" = "host2" ) ]]; then
            echo "(categorie $categorie; client $client): requirements are met"
        else
            echo "(categorie $categorie; client $client): requirements not met"
        fi
    done
done
```

Output:

```
(categorie DG; client host1): requirements not met
(categorie DG; client host1): requirements not met
(categorie DG; client host2): requirements not met
(categorie DG; client host2): requirements not met
(categorie DG; client other): requirements are met
(categorie DG; client other): requirements are met
(categorie DI; client host1): requirements not met
(categorie DI; client host1): requirements not met
(categorie DI; client host2): requirements not met
(categorie DI; client host2): requirements not met
(categorie DI; client other): requirements are met
(categorie DI; client other): requirements are met
(categorie XX; client host1): requirements not met
(categorie XX; client host1): requirements not met
(categorie XX; client host2): requirements not met
(categorie XX; client host2): requirements not met
(categorie XX; client other): requirements not met
(categorie XX; client other): requirements not met
```

The pairs of lines are always the same — the expressions are equivalent.  And the results are, I believe, what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is it. I use the `&&` instead of the `||` in the client check. I hadn't thought that the negated OR will match anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Since any string is always unequal to at least one of two differing strings, the part after the `&&` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around negating OR by comparing to patterns instead of doing multiple comparisons, which simplifies the test to

```
if [[ $categorie == D[GI] ]] && [[ $client != host[12] ]]; then
    echo "requirements are met"
else
    echo "requirements not met"
fi
```